# Calculating averages using QUERY and INDIRECT

Tags: google-sheets, average, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have the below sheets:

[image]

I'm trying to calculate the averages of the values from 2015-2019 for each date in the following sheet:

[image]

This is straightforward using AVERAGE. But I'm trying to calculate the averages for all the years based on the titles B1,C1 (and the corresponding sheets).

I tried using INDIRECT to point B1 to tomato sheet, but I'm not sure how to incorporate it with QUERY to calculate all the averages of the years from 2015-2019.

Here's the desired result using AVERAGE:

[image]

How do I achieve the above but with QUERY and based on the sheet names corresponding to data in row 1 (B1, C1 so on).

[Here's the sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FL7pCcL1sU3-_jUZduYNSGowU7blt6Bnq0KE7jQZv6A/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paste in **B2** and drag to the right:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(INDIRECT(B1&"!B2:Z")), 
 "select "&TEXTJOIN(",", 1, IF(LEN($A2:$A), 
 "avg(Col"&ROW($A2:$A)-ROW($A2)+1&")", ))&"")), "select Col2"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: That's awesome. I know I'm asking much but it would be awesome if you could give a brief explanation of what's going on. Thanks!

Comment: sure, here is detailed explanation: https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/find-max-value-in-each-row-in-google-sheets/